# How to decrypt sha1-encrypted String in Java

Tags: java, encryption, hash, cryptography, sha1

Is it possible to decrypt some string which was earlier encrypted with the SHA-1 algorithm in Java?

Comment: SHA-1 is a hash, not an encryption algorithm. If you're trying to extract a string from it's SHA-1 hash, good luck. That's called a pre-image attack.

Comment: It's _possible_, but would require computational resources and time, as sha1-encrypted data isn't meant to be decrypted once encrypted.

Comment: I think the question should be how computationally intensive it is to decrypt sha1. What does Java have to do with it? If you have a good algorithm, you can use any language to code it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SHA1 is a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), and the entire point is that you can't undo it. If it was possible to reverse the hash (find the input for a given hash), it wouldn't be useful. If you need to encrypt something and later decrypt it, you should use an [encryption function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)  or [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA).

However, for very simple inputs it may be possible to [crack the hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking) by guessing what the input was and checking if the hash is the same.

Example Python code:

```py
def crack_hash(hash_to_crack, hash_function, list_of_guesses):
    # Try to hash everything in our guess list
    for guess in list_of_guesses:
        new_hash = hash_function(guess)
        # if the hashes match, we found it
        if new_hash == hash_to_crack:
            return guess
    # If none of them match, give up
    return None
```

Of course, if you actually want to crack hashes efficiently, using software like [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) or [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/) is probably your best bet. Note that this usually works on passwords since they're short and easy to guess, but the difficulty increases exponentially as the input increases. You can crack every SHA-1 hash with a 6-character input in minutes, while cracking one with 16 characters would take trillions of years on average.

Comment: This method would require obscene amounts of space and time with a reasonably-sized list. A more practical alternative is to utilize a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) in order to apply a time-memory tradeoff. This method is useless for salted hashes, though

Comment: @jsvk - I'm not saying it's a good idea. In fact, I was hoping the example would illustrate how pointless it is unless you have a good idea what to guess. It could be improved, but realistically, no one uses their own password cracker -- and certainly not one written in Python ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible, because SHA-1 is a hash - it's a one way ticket. If you want to crypt and decrypt a string then you'll need to use some encryption algorithm that uses key to generate encrypted data. Then you can encrypt data and after successfully decrypt it. For example AES. You can read about AES from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: it's impossible.

Because SHA-1 is a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), by the pigeonhole principle, it is mathematically impossible to reverse. There are only 2<sup>160</sup> possible SHA-1 hashes. Since there are an infinite number of possible input strings, there must be collisions (multiple inputs that hash to the same value). In general, there's no way you can know which of those strings was the original input.

However, real-world strings aren't completely arbitrary. If you know some information about your input string (e.g. that it was less than 5 characters long), with high probability, the input is unique. Unfortunately for you, hash functions like SHA-1 are intentionally computationally infeasible to invert. (There are theoretical attacks on SHA-1, but I don't think any are currently considered even near feasible.)

So if you need to recover hashed data, you have to use brute force: try SHA-1ing each string of length less than *n*, and see if the hash matches. But there are exponentially many strings of length up to *n*, so this quickly becomes infeasible.

**There is one possible way to recover hashed data before the end of the universe**. Your only hope is to use a more sophisticated method, such as [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). This will *only* work if you know that your original string was very short (less than ~15 characters). Even for short strings, it will take a long time (and gigabytes of disk space) to pre-compute the table.

Comment: please update: It is very well possible, I just need the algorithm. [sha1-decrypter](http://www.stringfunction.com/sha1-decrypter.html) is the link to the page where you can find the online decrypter

Comment: @VineetVerma: That's not a decrypter; it's a reverse lookup. The code it uses is essentially, `Map<SHA1, byte[]> lookup = new HashMap<SHA1, byte[]>(); /*add some common inputs*/; return lookup.get(sha1sum);`. It'll only work if they happen to have added the input you're looking for to the map.